# Custom Button component: shadow is clipped

Tags: android, android-layout

I have custom LoadingButton class implemented as `FrameLayout` which is then used inside XMLs as component. Its basically `Button` but made completely custom with its own layout and components.

What I want is to add shadow there (elevation, translationZ) but this shadow is clipped everywhere.
I want to have this button dynamic that I can adjust its margins or change its shape like adding static width and height on different screens without distorting shadow around. Shadow is clipped either from top or bottom all the time.

Example of xml view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="CustomRes" type="com.project.utils.CustomResources"/>
    </data>

    <merge
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonParent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buttonText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:lines="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.project.components.loading_indicator.LoadingIndicator
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </merge>
</layout>
```

Class:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class LoadingButton : FrameLayout {

    @StyleableRes
    internal val btnIcoIndex = 0
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @StyleableRes
    internal val btnTextResIndex = 1
    @StyleableRes
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    internal val btnTextIndex = 2
    @StyleableRes
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    internal val btnTextSizeIndex = 3

    private val buttonParent: LinearLayout
    private val progressBar: LoadingIndicator
    private val buttonIcon: ImageView
    private val buttonText: TextView
    private var buttonTextVal: String? = null

    init {
        CustomResources.inflateLayout(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.loading_button, this)
        buttonParent = findViewById(R.id.buttonParent)
        buttonIcon = findViewById(R.id.buttonIcon)
        buttonText = findViewById(R.id.buttonText)
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress)

        buttonText.addOnLayoutChangeListener { v, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
            textViewInitWidth = maxOf(v.measuredWidth, textViewInitWidth)
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        parseAttrs(context)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        parseAttrs(context, attrs)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        parseAttrs(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    private fun parseAttrs(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int? = null) {
        //Load from custom attributes
        setLoading(false)
        val sets = intArrayOf(R.attr.l_buttonIcon, R.attr.l_buttonTextId, R.attr.l_buttonText, R.attr.l_buttonTextSize)
        if (attrs != null){
            val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, sets)
            val buttonIco = typedArray.getResourceId(btnIcoIndex, 0)
            val buttonTxtRes = typedArray.getText(btnTextResIndex)?.let { res->
                App.getString(res as String).toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).replaceFirstChar { it.toUpperCase() }
            }
            val buttonTxtRaw = typedArray.getText(btnTextIndex)?.let { it as String }?:"null"
            val buttonTxtSize = typedArray.getDimension(btnTextSizeIndex, resources.getDimension(R.dimen.text_medium))
            val buttonStyle = attrs.styleAttribute

            App.log("RawTextButton: $buttonTxtRaw, hasValue: ${typedArray.getString(btnTextIndex)}")
            setButtonTextSize(buttonTxtSize)
            buttonTxtRes?.let { setButtonText(buttonTxtRes) }?:kotlin.run{ setButtonText(buttonTxtRaw) }
            setButtonIcon(buttonIco)
            buttonParent.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            buttonTextVal = buttonTxtRes?.let { buttonTxtRes.toString() }?:buttonTxtRaw
            typedArray.recycle()

            clipToPadding = false
            clipChildren = false

            when(buttonStyle){
                R.style.button_primary -> {
                    App.log("BtnStyleId - primary")
                    setupTextStyle(buttonStyle)
                    setProgBarColor(R.color.button_light)
                    setIconTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.button_light))
                    maybeSetAmbientShadow(R.color.button_primary)
                }
                R.style.button_secondary -> {
                    App.log("BtnStyleId - secondary")
                    setupTextStyle(buttonStyle)
                    setProgBarColor(R.color.button_primary)
                    setIconTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.button_light))
                    maybeSetAmbientShadow(R.color.button_primary)
                }
                R.style.button_secondary_alert -> {
                    App.log("BtnStyleId - secondary alert")
                    setupTextStyle(buttonStyle)
                    setProgBarColor(R.color.button_invalid)
                    setIconTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.button_invalid))
                    maybeSetAmbientShadow(R.color.button_invalid)
                }
                else -> App.log("BtnStyleId -> $buttonStyle")
            }
        } else {
            App.log("BtnStyleId -> attrs==null")
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    private fun setupTextStyle(buttonStyle: Int){
        val attrs = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.textAppearance)
        val typedAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(buttonStyle, attrs)
        val textAppearance = typedAttrs.getResourceId(0, 0)
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(buttonText, textAppearance)
        typedAttrs.recycle()
    }

    private fun setProgBarColor(color: Int){
        progressBar.setColorTint(color)
    }

    fun setIconTint(color: Int){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
            buttonIcon.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(color, BlendMode.SRC_IN)
        } else {
            App.log("setting color filter")
            buttonIcon.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        }
    }

    private fun maybeSetAmbientShadow(color: Int){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
            outlineAmbientShadowColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, color)
            outlineSpotShadowColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, color)
        }
    }
}
```

I need some variable to set which will set `clipToPadding false and clipChildren false` for every single screen where this button is implemented without rewriting 80+ xml files. Because some screens have marginTop set for this button but not marginBottom, and that will cause clipping even if I set those 2 parameters to false. Clearly bad design from Android for handling shadows.

Base style for primary and secondary button:

```
<style name="button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/button_padding_start</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/button_padding_end</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/button_padding_top</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/button_padding_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:translationZ">4dp</item>
        <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
        <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
</style>
```

Usage:

```
<com.project.components.loading_button.LoadingButton
     android:id="@+id/loginButton"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
     app:l_buttonTextId="button_login"
     style="@style/button.primary" />
```

Comment: If you mean that `LoadingButton` extends `FrameLayout`, then `LoadingButton` is what should have the shadow settings, not any of the `View`s nested/inflated inside of it. The shadow will then behave like it would on a regular `Button`, without having to adjust the clip settings on `LoadingButton`'s parents.

Comment: Yeah LoadingButton is extending FrameLayout and inside I have some TextView and ProgressBar which are also animated. (parent xml has also merge tag)

Comment: Where's the shadow, exactly? That is, where are you setting the `elevation`/`translationZ`?

Comment: inside style for button - added additional code

Comment: At this point, it's not clear what the specific problem is. A few things are off in the given setup – I'm assuming from debugging attempts – but the parts that we can test have normal shadow behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvlDm.png. The only clip setting that makes sense so far is `clipToPadding="false"` on `LoadingButton`'s parent, but that's just how shadows work everywhere. Setting `clipChildren="false"` there has no effect on `LoadingButton`'s own shadow. However, it would affect shadows on `LoadingButton`'s internal `View`s, but there are no such settings in the given example.

Comment: I just realized that using that particular icon for an example image here probably wasn't the best idea. Ignore the shadow on the android; it's not related.